# Angular PrimeNG DataTable sort

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

The code link is:https://plnkr.co/edit/V9ZkLzDeVo15ngIu2Glo?p=preview

My template is:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="cars">
<p-headerColumnGroup>
    <p-row>
        <p-column header="Vin" rowspan="2" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
        <p-column header="Info" colspan="3"></p-column>
    </p-row>
    <p-row>
        <p-column header="Year" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
        <p-column header="Brand" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
        <p-column header="Color" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    </p-row>
</p-headerColumnGroup>
<p-column field="vin"></p-column>
<p-column field="year"></p-column>
<p-column field="brand"></p-column>
<p-column field="color"></p-column>
```

The sort function will not work when there is a colgroup header. Can someone please suggest me on this?

Answer (score 2):

That's because `p-dataTable` could not find connections between headers and columns. Adding `sortField` to header will help establishing them:

```
<p-headerColumnGroup>
    <p-row>
        <p-column header="Vin" sortField="vin" rowspan="2" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
        <p-column header="Info" colspan="3"></p-column>
    </p-row>
    <p-row>
        <p-column header="Year" sortField="year" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
        <p-column header="Brand" sortField="brand" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
        <p-column header="Color" sortField="color" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    </p-row>
</p-headerColumnGroup>
```